# Why can't I create this role with perms to another role

Tags: postgresql

This doesn't work

```
CREATE ROLE "role-one" LOGIN;
CREATE ROLE "other_role" LOGIN WITH "role-one";
```

I get this error

```
ERROR:  unrecognized role option "role-one"
LINE 1: CREATE ROLE "other_role" WITH "role-one";
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't find examples online that make it clear to me what the syntax is. From what I have seen this should work.

How do I create a new role with LOGIN and add it to another role named role-one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use a wrong syntax. Let me cite the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html):

> ```
> CREATE ROLE name [ [ WITH ] option [ ... ] ]
>
> where option can be:
> ...
>    | IN ROLE role_name [, ...]
>    | ROLE role_name [, ...]
> ...
> ```
>
> `IN ROLE` ***role_name***
>
> The IN ROLE clause lists one or more existing roles to which the new role will be immediately added as a new member. (Note that there is no option to add the new role as an administrator; use a separate GRANT command to do that.)
>
> `ROLE` ***role_name***
>
> The ROLE clause lists one or more existing roles which are automatically added as members of the new role. (This in effect makes the new role a “group”.)
> ...

(I skipped uninteresting parts).

So, correct syntax would be either:

- if you want `other_role` to be a member of `role-one`:

```
CREATE ROLE "role-one" LOGIN;
CREATE ROLE "other_role" LOGIN IN ROLE "role-one";
```

- if you want `role-one` to become a member of `other_role` (the reverse):

```
CREATE ROLE "role-one" LOGIN;
CREATE ROLE "other_role" LOGIN ROLE "role-one";
```

Notice keywords `ROLE` and `IN ROLE` which you skipped, apparently.

There is also a way to create role and grant a membership in two distinct commands, which is perfectly explained with detailed example, again, in another [manual page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/role-membership.html):

```
CREATE ROLE "role-one" LOGIN;
CREATE ROLE "other_role" LOGIN;
GRANT "role-one" TO "other_role";
```

In this case, `other_role` will be a member of `role-one`. To do the reverse thing, swap them in the last GRANT.

Also, unrelated advices:

- don't name roles "other_role" and "role-one". Either first one should be "other-role" or second "role_one", so both contain dash or underscore. Be consistent. This really helps to keep things straight and easier;
- if you are making role a "group", consider adding it *without* LOGIN option. Let it be strictly a group.